# AppBarLayout DragCallback in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to replicate this code in Xamarin Android

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
       @Override
       public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
            return false;
       }
});
params.setBehavior(behavior);
```

I don't see any method or callback declaration for `DragCallback` or even `CanDrag` override in Android Design Support Library (appcompat). Basically I am stuck at this place..

Any way to implement this in an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on version 23.1.1.0 of the Xamarin.Android.Support.Design NuGet package? You will find all the methods and types you need in that version.

The only difference is that `AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback` is an abstract class so you have to subclass it, but you can't do that kind of inline overriding of methods like you can in Java anyway. So this should work if you update the Support.Design library:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams parameters = 
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)mAppBarLayout.LayoutParameters;
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
behavior.SetDragCallback (new MyDragCallBack ());
parameters.Behavior = behavior;
```

and then subclass the DragCallback class:

```
public class MyDragCallBack : AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback
{
    public override bool CanDrag (AppBarLayout p0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This wasn't there back when I posted this question. Found it in update. Thanks anyway :-)